# jquery: execute a function when form is loaded

Tags: jquery

I want to execute different functions when several forms in the document are "ready".
I tried

```
<form id="id1" onload="function();" action="save" method="POST">
```

but I noticed that it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the right way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: use $(document).ready(..

Comment: HTML incorrectness...you can't have several forms in one web page (technically speaking, practically is a different story, I would suggest you to find another approach as you will find other problems while doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code goes here
});`

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers - not the answer I liked but the answer I expected.
So I will try to make it work in a different way

Comment: this is not a answer. Add comment to answer instead. :)